# How do I retrieve the contents of an Azure blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've never done this before but I am saving an object to Azure blob storage by turning it into a string and streaming to Azure.  I've checked the blob in Azure and it looks exactly how I would expect, as this:

```
{"ClientID":"xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx","ClientSecret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","RedirectURL":"","GrantToken":"GRANT token","RefreshToken":null,"AccessToken":null,"ExpiresIn":null,"UserMail":null,"Id":null}
```

When I retrieve the blob, it appears I am only getting the meta-data and the Content element is blank.  Here is the code to retreive the blob

```
        public Token GetToken(UserSignature user, Token token)
        {

            try
            {
                var connectionString = "connection-string-goes-here";
                
                BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "container-name-goes-here", "blob-name-goes-here");
                var download = blobClient.DownloadContent();
                BinaryData data = new BinaryData(download);
                var test = data.ToArray();
                var test2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(test);
                 Token result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthToken>(test2);

                return token;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //ToDo: implement error logging to blob
                
            }
```

And here is the result after calling '''GetString(test)''' The very last element is Content and its empty.

```
{"Value":{"Details":{"BlobType":0,"ContentLength":236,"ContentType":"application/octet-stream","ContentHash":"t6oIPlIWyChaWSo9tseiMw==","LastModified":"2021-09-12T18:14:36+00:00","Metadata":{},"ContentRange":null,"ETag":"\u00220x8D976192D9F53B0\u0022","ContentEncoding":null,"CacheControl":null,"ContentDisposition":null,"ContentLanguage":null,"BlobSequenceNumber":0,"CopyCompletedOn":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","CopyStatusDescription":null,"CopyId":null,"CopyProgress":null,"CopySource":null,"CopyStatus":0,"LeaseDuration":0,"LeaseState":0,"LeaseStatus":0,"AcceptRanges":"bytes","BlobCommittedBlockCount":0,"IsServerEncrypted":true,"EncryptionKeySha256":null,"EncryptionScope":null,"BlobContentHash":null,"TagCount":0,"VersionId":null,"IsSealed":false,"ObjectReplicationSourceProperties":null,"ObjectReplicationDestinationPolicyId":null,"LastAccessed":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"},"Content":{}}}
```

I need to get the blob and turn it back into a c# object.  I've read so many articles and they all show a slightly different way of doing it.    Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient` method to get your blob.

```cs
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(yourConnectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = await blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(yourContainerName);


// Get specific blob
var blob = await containerClient.GetBlobClient(yourBlobName);
```

It returns a `BlobClient`. You can use BlobClient's **Uri** property to see the image you've saved or if you want to download the content you can use `DownloadContentAsync` method.

```
var content = await blob.DownloadContentAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks Engincan, but I am using the blob client and its getting the meta data just not the content.  
` 
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "container-name-goes-here", "blob-name-goes-here");
                var download = blobClient.DownloadContent();
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this post and I don't know any way to do this but to answer it.  I didn't get the error fixed but I also discovered I was taking the wrong approach.  Thanks for assisting me.